# AngularJS: tracking which checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, onchange, angularjs-controller

In an HTML form, I need to track which checkboxes get checked so I can insert it in my query object that is to be posted to the backend.

I have the following three checkboxes in an array in the $scope:

```
$scope.typeCheckBoxes = [
      {label: "A", val: true},
      {label: "B", val: false},
      {label: "C", val: false}
    ];
```

and this below is my template for rendering the checkboxes in the form:

```
<span ng-repeat="chk in typeCheckBoxes">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="chk.val" id="chk.label" ng-change="addType(this)" />
            <label>{{chk.label}}</label>
</span>
```

and in my controller, I tried to create the function **addType()** to add the checked checkbox to my query object:

```
$scope.queryObj = {
types: []
};

$scope.addType = function(e) {
   var selectedBox = angular.element(e.id); // not working
   if (selectedBox) {
     $scope.queryObj.types.push(selectedBox);
   }

};
```

However, I am not sure how I can get the `id` of the checked checkbox. your help is appreciated very much.

Comment: you can take an advantage of two way binding of angular, you can iterate through the `scope.typeCheckBoxes`  again and if val= true then take that id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you are missing is, you should write the `addType` function inside scope in order to fire it on change of checkbox(because you use `ng-change` directive that will lookup for function inside current scope)
You could get ng-change event inside your controller and do simple forEach on object.

**CODE**

```
$scope.addType = function(){
   angular.forEach($scope.typeCheckBoxes, function(value, index) {
      if(value.val)
       console.log('value.id');//here you can get selected value
   });
}
```

**Update:**

Actually you could get required checked/unchecked label's list by using Angular `$filter` service to filter the array and get checked and unchecked list by it. Then for getting there label you need to do One for loop.

**CODE**

```
 $scope.$watch('typeCheckBoxes', function (newObj, oldObj) {
   var types, 
   checked = $filter('filter')(newObj, {'val': true}), //checked list
   unchecked = $filter('filter')(newObj, {'val': false}); //unchecked list
   console.log(checked);
   console.log(unchecked);
   for (var i=0; i< checked.length; i++) {
      types.push(checked[i].label); //adding checked labels to type array 
   }
}, true);
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/251/)

This would help you, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for you to do this in your controller :

```
$scope.$watch('typeCheckBoxes', function(newObject, oldObject) {
// You can do what you want with your newObject here
}, true);
```

Don't forget the **true** as the second parameter. This is allow you to watch an entire object and not just a simple value. This $watch will be triggered at each change.

Because the ids of your checkboxes are the labels, you will have it too in the newObject.

Comment: how do I know the newObject is checked?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by **@jlouazel** 's suggestion, I did some research on `$scope.$watch()` method, which in my opinion is ***more Angular***. So I came up with the following solution, which works but lacks the flexibility of getting the checked checkbox directly. I have to use a for-loop to check which checkbox(es) in the checkbox group get checked/unchecked.

```
$scope.$watch('typeCheckBoxes | filter: {val: true}', function(newObj, oldObj) {

    // checked ones
    for (var props in newObj) {
      console.log(newObj[props].label);
      types.push(newObj[props].label); //save the checked label
    }

    //unchecked ones
    for (var props in oldObj) {
      console.log('oldObj[' + props + '] =' + oldObj[props].label);
      types.splice(types.indexOf(oldObj[props].label, 1); // remove the unchecked label
    }
  }, true);
```

It's really cumbersome to use for-loops to find the checked checkboxes.  So, I need to improve (*if possible at all*) the above code to get the checked ones directly rather than using a loop. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious to know that why you put second for loop?

Comment: because I also need to remove the selected checkbox from the "types" array if it's unchecked